# How to raise a field error in a custom way from the view in FlaskWTF

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, wtforms

I have a registration form created by the class:

```
class RegistrationForm (Form):
   username = StringField('username', validators = [DataRequired()])
```

and The model:

```
class User (db.Model):
    UserName = db.Column(db.String(25),nullable=False, unique=True)
```

I'd like to check if the field for username for duplicates in the server and then return an error of that field ... is it possible without using flash messages ?

since I'm using a macro formhelper to show field errors next to the field which contains errors..

or is there a way to specify that this field is unique in the Validators ?

Thanks:

The macro:

```
{% macro render_field(field) %}
  {{ field(**kwargs)|safe }}
  {% if field.errors %}
    <ul>
    {% for error in field.errors %}
      <li style="color:red">{{ error }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
        <li style="color:red">{{ error_message }}</li>
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a method "validate_<name of field>" on the form.  This will run whatever custom validation you want.  In this case, check if the username is already used and raise an error if it is.

```
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms.fields import StringField
from wtforms.validators import ValidationError, InputRequired

class RegistrationForm(Form):
    username = StringField('username', validators=[InputRequired()])

    def validate_username(self, field):
        # count the number of user ids for that username
        # if it's not 0, there's a user with that username already
        if db.session.query(db.func.count(User.id)).filter_by(username=field.data).scalar():
            raise ValidationError('this username is already taken')
```

As an optimization, this counts the id field rather than actually fetching or counting the entire model.

See the [WTForms docs](http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/validators.html) for more information.

---

Note that some people consider this a security issue because an attacker could determine if a name is registered by trying them here and seeing if it fails.